# Blender ram usage goes through the roof for no reason

Tags: cycles-render-engine

For some reason blender at times uses way more ram than needed. A fresh scene will use 5.5gigs of vram opposed to original scene running out of vram(24gigs).

The only way I've found to resolve this issue is to create a new blend file and append the collections from the scene.

I've tried purging, deleting temp files. Is there a solution other than creating a new blend file and appending everything?